# Data-binding to ng-model inside of checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

My problem is that I'm trying to access these checkboxes from inside the controller so I can set them to true from there.

For some reason, I can't figure out the correct ng-model to use for these checkboxes such that I have the ability to do so, while maintaining that each one has a unique name.

```
       <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <accordion-heading>{{group.title}}</accordion-heading>
        <div ng-repeat="collection in group.collections">
          <div class="checkbox collection-legend" style="background-color: {{collection.color}}">
            <label><input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleCollection(collection.key)" ng-model="checkboxes[collection.key]"> {{collection.name}}: <em>{{collection.description}}</em></label>
            <div class="customFields">
              <label ng-repeat="(key, val) in collection.queries" ng-if="key != 'default' && key != 'dateRangeKey'">
              <input class="form-text" ng-model="customProperties[collection.name + '-' + key]" type="text"><em>{{key}}</em></label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </accordion-group>
```

For some context, I'm trying to set up a "restore session" method, where the user can bring back up old forms submitted without having to fill them out again, so I have the list of checkboxes that need to be "rechecked", I just can't figure out how to name my model so I can do it.

ng-model="checkboxes[collection.key]" seems like it should work here. Any advice?

And then $scope.checkboxes[key] = true in the controller. (key matches collection.key; I've already confirmed this). Getting a "can not set (key) of undefined" error.

Here is the JS:

```
    $scope.session.collections.forEach(function(c){
      $scope.toggleCollection(c);
      console.log(c + ' '+ typeof c);
      $scope.checkboxes = {
        c: true
      };
    });
```

Solution: Never initialized $scope.checkboxes as an empty object. Works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you pasted certainly works, I've verified it here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ho8art1t/

checkboxes should be something along those lines:

```
$scope.checkboxes = {
    a: true,
    b: false,
    c: true
};
```

You should either paste the JS that goes with it or just check that your objects are placed similarly as in that fiddle.

Comment: Added my JS. There must be something wrong with my syntax, because what I have for collection is pretty much exactly what you have in the fiddle, and it works.

Comment: You have the assignment in a forEach, are you sure you meant to do that? It would override the checkboxes override each time and only leave a single item c in it for ever. Otherwise, we'll probably also need the JS which sets up $scope.collections

Comment: Yeah, I did mean to do that, but I noticed something...when I assign "c"...it just creates an object {c: true}, instead of using the variable c. Is there a way to force it to be the string that's passed from the forEach, instead of an entirely new object?

Comment: Ugh, I figured it out. I never initalized $scope.checkboxes as an empty object. Derp.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you really want it to only have the single prop, first clear it ($scope.checkboxes = {}) then set the prop using the accessor ($scope.checkboxes[c] = true). If you want to set all keys (which I'd guess you want), just use $scope.checkboxes[c] = true